# InputReportReceived not raised for HID device

Tags: .net, vb.net, hid, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to get an input from a HID device (waiter lock) that is connected via USB to a Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 Iot .
If you put the key on the lock the ID of that key is "typed".
But the InputReceived event is never raised.

I don't receive any errors and _device seems to be the right one.

What can I do about this?

Here is my code:

```
Private Async Sub StartSub()
    Dim selector As String = HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(65440, 1, 4292, 33975)

    Dim devices = Await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector)
    If devices.Count > 0 Then
        _device = Await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(devices(0).Id, FileAccessMode.Read)
        If _device IsNot Nothing Then
            Debug.WriteLine($"ID:{devices(0).Id} UP:{_device.UsagePage} UID:{_device.UsageId}")
            AddHandler _device.InputReportReceived, AddressOf InputReceived
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub InputReceived(sender As HidDevice, args As HidInputReportReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim l As Long = args.Report.GetNumericControl(65440, 1).Value
End Sub

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
      <Device Id="vidpid:10C4 84B7">
        <Function Type="usage:FFA0 *"/>
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What the HID device do you use?

Comment: I use this device: [link](http://www.glancetron.com/ProIBR1300.html) Glancetron 1300

Comment: Did you declare the hid device capability in the project manifest file? see to https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn263091

Comment: Yes, I've added the "humaninterfacedevice" to the capabilities.

Comment: I gave up. It couldn't find a solution and I've read somewhere that it is not possible to do this with "normal" HID devices only custom HID devices.
Instead I used the VCOM cable available for the Glancetron. This works quite well.